# How would I activate iphone voice activation programmatically?

Tags: iphone, voice, activation

I'm looking for some code, that I can use in my iPhone app, that at a given event, Voice Activation will be triggered, without the need of a user holding down the home button.
I would just need Apple's native implementation. I don't need to interfere with its functionality.

By the way: if there are some private API's, that would be good enough. It's for personal use only.

Comment: Do you want your App to be in the AppStore?

Comment: Do you want to add voice command to control your app? Because Voice Activation will only control the iPhone and it's software.

Comment: (Sorry, I've been away). I don't need the app to appear in the AppStore, and I want my App to start up Voice Activation, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I went out and send this question to Apple. I don't think I'm breaking any NDA when I quote them answering "Our engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations."
They suggest me to file a Feature Request, which I will do right now. If this is ever going to be rewarded, you'll be the first to know.